# replacing a parameter with the use of a pointer

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, recursion

i did a program which counts the amount of letters in each cycle. But i don't like the idea that i used 2 parameters. I know that it could be done with only one, using a pointer, but i don't know how. I tried **char*str2=char str1**, but the output value was wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int zyk(char *str1,char *str2){

    if (*str1 != '\0'){
        if (*str2 != *(str1+1)){
            return 1 + zyk(str1+1,str2);

        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    char str1[] = "abcdabcd";
    char str2[] = "abcdabcd";
    cout <<  zyk(str1,str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this using recursion, and not just a loop?

Comment: @ScottHunter - Because it's exam season :-)

Comment: "But i don't like the idea that i used 2 parameters." Why? That's completely fine.

Comment: are we guaranteed a cycle will only contain non-repeating characters?

Comment: @ScottHunter-On my exam i'm not allowed to use loops within the function, so i'm trying to avoid them.

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is

Comment: @DeathTails I don't know as well, just wondering if it's possible

Comment: @Dar Brett - Can i replace the parameter "*str2" somehow with a pointer within the function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I think you may have a logic error in whatever it is. I think you'd be able to replace *str2 in the if statement with 'a' and remove str2 as a parameter and you'd get the same behaviour.

Comment: @Dar Brett - You are right. My idea was to only get the first char of the word and that's why i made "str2".  Never thought of literally using the 'a'. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single parameter that is either an array of your 2 pointers, or a `struct` with your 2 pointers.  You could have no parameters, and use global variable(s).

Note: I'm not suggesting these are *good* ideas, just that they are possible.

Comment: i did it with global variables and got the correct output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're doing this for a class I'd shy away from globals...instructors tend to discourage it :^)

Comment: Globals should be a NONO!